# pass an attribute of the context item to fn:id()

Tags: xslt

I would like to clarify the following behavior.
When using the `fn:id()` and passing the `@attribute` which is child of the context item, I get the empty sequence:

```
   <xsl:template match="perfRes" mode="perfRes">    
            <xsl:variable name="listItem" select="$lists//id(@attribute)"/>
    <xsl:template/>
```

When passing the same attribute, but as a variable, the result is correct:

```
<xsl:template match="perfRes" mode="perfRes">   
    <xsl:variable name="attribute" select="@attribute"/>    
    <xsl:variable name="listItem" select="$lists//id($attribute)"/>
<xsl:template/>
```

So I suppose that in the first case this @attribute refers not to the context item but to something else, **to what?**

P.S. The value of $lists is a document-node().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `$lists/id(current()/@attribute)` to select the `@attribute` of the matched `perfRes` element and pass it to the `id` function. Your current attempt `$lists//id(@attribute)` is equivalent to `$lists/descendant-or-self::node()/id(@attribute)` so it calls the `id` function on the `@attribute` of any descendant node of `$lists`.